# How to complete Career with 126%?

Tags: achievements, ios, death-rally-2012

I'm playing Death Rally on the iPhone and I'm stuck at 124% out of 126% I've got max cars and weapon upgrades. I've beat the adversary.

My fame level is at God level. Looking through the options "stats" I don't see any stat with x/y not fulfilled. I haven't killed every boss type according to the stats or won races on every difficulty.

Anything anyone can think of that makes up that last 2% to complete a career.

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out too. I'm stuck at 154%

Comment: I thought the maximum % was 192%

Comment: **Come on, I'll shootcha...**

Answer (score 1):

You just need to complete all the achievements in the list and do at least 1 race of every type: marathon, upstream, no guns,...

Comment: You might not have done a 'marathon' race type yet.

Answer (score -2):

How to Kill the Adversary to get the Uncrown Adversary achievement.

Comment: Dougnukem states in the question that he's already beaten the Adversary.